# Neurons during Numb feeling

Tags: human-biology, brain, central-nervous-system, peripheral-nervous-system

We become numb when there is short supply of blood to some parts, as mentioned [here](http://www.thehindu.com/sci-tech/science/question-corner-numbness/article3712922.ece).

If that is the reason, why don't neurons and other cells die at that part if they don't receive oxygen and other things needed?

Answer (score 1):

A lower supply of blood does not mean no supply of blood, so my guess is there's generally enough to keep stuff alive for some time. But if the supply is restricted for long periods (think frostbite), then stuff starts to die.

Also, the sensory neuron endings in the skin are normally just one long projection from a cell body, the major components of the neuron are protected by being located in e.g. [The Dorsal Root Ganglion.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dorsal_root_ganglion)

Comment: True, I was thinking more from a frostbite point of view, i.e. stuff will die eventually, but mostly surface tissue rather than neurons etc.

Comment: @mgkrebbs I'll remove my comment, as it's a bit misleading. I meant to refer to the article which says "reduced supply of blood to the limbs" implying that blood flow to the limbs is lost, which isn't true.

Answer (score -1):

Simply put, the cells and "other stuff" WOULD die if the blood flow and/or oxygen were too severe, and would be cut off for too long.

It would probably take some time though.

Comment: The neurons stop working in lack of blood, why dont other cells stop?

Comment: For your response to be better received, please provide supporting information, which may include a quote or two from a reputable source, and/or links to those sources. As it stands, your response comes off as pure speculation, and is too nondescript.

Comment: @Charles Is it speculation to say cells will die in the end if blood flow stops? Do I really have to provide sources for this? Now seriously.... as they say, "LOL".... You could as well ask me to prove to you an apple will fall downwards if it detaches itself from the tree.

Comment: @Ram Keswani, your question doesn't make sense to me. I don't understand what you are asking. Do you mean to say you believe cells go on living if no oxygen is provided anymore?

Comment: @Charles And besides why don't you ask the same thing of user Oliver Houston? He too seems to blindly assume cells don't survive without nourishment.... LOL

Comment: @ObiwanKeNoobie *Is it speculation to say cells will die in the end if blood flow stops?"* -- depending on the amount of time that's lapsed, yes, most definitely that's a speculative statement. Also, when you say *"..in the end"*, are you implying that *eventually* all cells die without blood supply? If so, then this is a trivial statement to make, since it is so obvious, as you yourself have pointed out. And, since that is the entirely of your response, respectfully speaking, I find your response not helpful.

Comment: @ObiwanKeNoobie Sir see, we feel numb because neurons stop working, or work less efficient because of lack of oxyegn. Then the other cells near that area also lack blood and oxygen. If neurons work less efficiently, why don't other cells in that area not work less efficiently or stop working? Or do they work less efficiently and it doesn't matter much?

Comment: @ObiwanKeNoobie *"and "other stuff" WOULD die .. "* what "other stuff"? This is **way** too general for a scientific community. *"It would probably take some time though."* -- This statement is extremely, extremely vague and nondescript, supported by absolutely no scientific information. I hope you are starting to see my point..

Comment: @ObiwanKeNoobie The entire focus of the OP is on the amount of time that blood flow is restricted from a body region, with respect to any detrimental effects that may occur as a result. That being said, a brief description of the relationship between blood & neurons/other cells in question would first be established, while doing so a time frame of cell death would be established, and then those conclusions would be tied back to the OP to ultimately address & answer their question. *This* would be an acceptably structured response to this specific question, IMO.

Comment: @Charles - "@ObiwanKeNoobie "and "other stuff" WOULD die .. " what "other stuff"? This is way too general for a scientific community." I bet it is. I was merely quoting the asker, that's why I put brackets around it as I found this not very scientific. And you are now pretending it is me ? LOL... I understand you want to be right but please, be fair. It should be clear to you the asker merely edited his question meanwhile, and rest assured I will have to say something about this in the meta talk.

Comment: @Charles - "@ObiwanKeNoobie Is it speculation to say cells will die in the end if blood flow stops?" -- depending on the amount of time that's lapsed, yes, most definitely that's a speculative statement. Also, when you say "..in the end", are you implying that eventually all cells die without blood supply? If so, then this is a trivial statement to make, since it is so obvious, as you yourself have pointed out. And, since that is the entirely of your response, respectfully speaking, I find your response not helpful. – Charles 1 hour ago" - Charles my boy as soon as I have the means I am going

Comment: ... going to report you for pestering me OK? Read again the nonsense you were replying to me. I have other things to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66909/discussion-between-charles-and-obiwan-kenoobie).

Comment: Sorry, impossible. I can't. I have spent almost the whole day on SE. It will have to wait for another day.